# Git - printf remote URL by parameter into console

Tags: git, macos, bash

I'm trying to write a BASH script that will `printf` the url of a git `remote` into the console, and the remote corresponds to a parameter to the function.

```
print-remote() {
    printf "Remote Url: $(git config --get remote.$1.url)"
}
```

And I would call it like:

```
print-remote origin
```

and it should print out

```
Remote Url: git@github.io:User/repository.git
```

But this isn't picking up my `$1`, and I'm just getting back

```
Remote Url:
```

I feel like I'm missing some syntax.

Comment: What is the output of `git config --get remote.origin.url`? The advice given in the answer is useful but your current function should be working anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your function to:

```
print-remote() {
   printf "Remote Url: %s\n" "$(git config --get remote."$1".url)"
}
```

Reason being that if output from `git` has any `%` characters or some other special `printf` characters then `printf` will try to use them as format parameter.

Or else just use `echo`:

```
print-remote() {
   echo "Remote Url: $(git config --get remote."$1".url)"
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, that first suggestion worked like a charm!